# C Sharp GUI/Socket Crashing on GUI Update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Whenever handleResponse calls the delegate function "func" my GUI crashes with no exception. The delegate function appends text to a RichTextBox on the GUI.

If I call this.func in "connect" it works just fine.

```
private void handleResponse(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        this.func.Invoke("test");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

public void connect(string ip, int port, delegateFunction func) {     
    try
    {
        connection.Connect(ip, port);
        socket = connection.Client;
        this.func = func;            
        socket.BeginReceive(incomingBuffer, 0, incomingBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, handleResponse, null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a threading issue. Your GUI probably has to be updated on a specific GUI thread. How switching to that thread is achieved is specific to the GUI framework you use.